# await task.delay helps in UI refresh faster, but how?

Tags: c#, .net, task-parallel-library, async-await

I have a view model that is fetching a row of records and displaying on the Windows phone UI..  This view model method which fetches the data is doing a lot of Tasks, all marked with Await operations..

Looks like below:

```
async Task GetData()
{

    var dataCollection = await GetSomeData();
    await DoThis();
    await DoThat();
}
```

The UI refreshes after the 'DoThis' call is invoked.
Now I just observed that if I introduce a Task.Delay in the code before other Tasks are done, the UI is refreshed immediately.. Which was my original Goal, to refresh the UI immediately after 'GetSomeData' Returns and then fire the other Tasks.

Looks like below:

```
async Task GetData()
{
    var dataCollection = await GetSomeData();
    await Task.Delay(100);
    await DoThis();
    await DoThat();
}
```

So what I understand from this, is that the UI thread gets opportunity to refresh after a call to Task.Delay is made. However without Task.Delay, if DoThis is called, some time is lost before it finds the first awaitable method in 'DoThis' so that it can return and continue with UI Refresh.

My questions are:

1. Have I understood it correct?
2. Is it safe to put this in production code?

Thanks in advance and hope I have explained clearly..

Pr

Below is Details of These methods as without those it is not clear what is going in the program.. :(

```
async Task<ObservableCollection<MyModel>> GetSomeData()
{
    return await Task.Run(() =>
    {
        using (var db = new MainModelDataContext())
        {
            List<MyModel> temp =
                db.Models.Where(Some condition)
                  .Take(30)
                  .ToList();
            var returnCollection = new ObservableCollection<MyModel>(temp);
            return returnCollection;
        }
}
```

The ObservableCollection is bound to a list control on the UI Page. This method is being called by the page view model.

```
async Task DoThis()
{
   // do some data processing and then post that to the Server 
   // this is the first awaitable method after the data processing

   await (an HttpClientHandler).PostAsync();
}
```

Task DoThat() also follows the same flow as DoThis.. The data processing is also wrapped in async-await Tasks and they are just working on some class properties.

Hope I am clear.. Thanks again all

Comment: What do `DoThis()` and `DoThat()` do? It sounds like they're effectively synchronous code which probably shouldn't be on the UI thread...

Comment: It might be that you have some synchronous code executing inside one of those methods and the call to `Task.Delay` is simply giving the UI thread a chance to run.

Comment: You need to post `GetSomeData` and `DoThis` methods. I assume something is running a long synchronous operation inside them.

Comment: Thanks @JonSkeet, The DoThis method is indeed an async method, it is calling a web Client async way..

Comment: It would really help if you'd show a short but *complete* program demonstrating the problem. Even with the answer you've accepted, it's still not clear exactly what's going on.

Comment: Thanks @JonSkeet, added the relevant code in the OP..

Comment: Except that that wouldn't compile as you're trying to use `await` within non-async methods. Why are you awaiting the return value of `Task.Run` at all? Why not just declare a non-async method that returns the task directly? The wrapping doesn't help...

Comment: They both are async methods, just added the async keyword which I had forgotten earlier.. My bad that I wrote the code in the OP in a clumsy way.. Anyways, the gist of the matter is that the Task.Delay is required because my data retrieval is essentially synchronous despite being in a Task.Run wrapper..

Comment: If you want to immediately return control to the caller, you can use `Task.Yield()`. But that would make your code better, but not good.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When you call `Task.Delay`, you return control to the UI message loop for those 100 milliseconds, and the UI message loop has the opportunity to process more messages from its queue. That's why you're experiencing the "refreshing" effect. If your `GetSomeData` method is truely asynchronous, your UI should remain responsive during its operation, and when it completes, it will continue to execute the next `await`.

If this effect doesn't happen, then that means your methods aren't really *asynchronous*, and its more likely that they are running a costly operation in a **synchronous** fashion which is blocking your UI thread.

Before putting this into production, you have to look into why you need `Task.Delay` to refresh your UI.

Comment: Thanks.. it makes sense.. GetSomeData just picks up some data from the database in a TAsk.Run wrapper. I do not have the parallel linq APIs to run due to some external limitations.. Hence this method is almost synchronous and thus the Task.Delay..

Comment: No, if it's actually returning the task, then it's suitably asynchronous. If you're using `Task.Result` within `GetSomeData` then *that* would be a problem. It's very hard to give details when we can't see any of your methods other than `GetData` :(

Comment: @PRE Jon is of course correct, we do need to see your methods to examine further what is going on. If you wrap it inside `Task.Run`, it still should be responsive.