# Task.Delay() releases UI Thread?

Tags: c#, multithreading, winforms, task-parallel-library

Could someone explain to me why this code does not block UI ? Im not creating any new thread/task and application just works fine.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Test1();
}

private async void Test1()
{
    var random = new Random();
    while (true)
    {
        try
        {
            textBox1.Text = random.Next(1, 100).ToString();
            textBox2.Text = random.Next(1, 100).ToString();
            await Task.Delay(5000);
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            break;
            throw;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25115446/await-task-delay-helps-in-ui-refresh-faster-but-how

Comment: I have check my mailbox every single day.  I check it and then after a day has gone by, I need to check it again.  How am I ever able to do anything other than check my mail if I have such a requirement?  Having a requirement to do something in X minutes/seconds/days/etc. doesn't mean you can't do anything between now and then.

Comment: There are **many** Q&A on Stack Overflow already, not to mention the wealth of information on the Internet, which explains how `async` and `await` work together to allow code to be written in an apparently synchronous, blocking manner without actually blocking the thread. See marked duplicate for one of the more popular ones.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Im not creating any new thread/task

Well, sort of... `Task.Delay` *does* create a new task - one that completes after 5 seconds.

Your code then calls `await` on that task, which *returns* from `Test1`. For more information about how `await` works, see my [`async` intro](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/02/async-and-await.html).

During those 5 seconds, your UI thread is free to do other work (like respond to user input). At the end of those 5 seconds, the task returned from `Task.Delay` completes, and the UI thread resumes executing `Test1`.

On a side note, you should avoid `async void`; in general, only use `async void` for event handlers. See my article on [`async` best practices](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj991977.aspx) for more information.